# Large Error Log Generation due to repetitive error on Wordpress website

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is very specific question and need suggestion specific to my website or server only.

Website: www[dot]admission[dot]aglasem[dot]com

My error log size increases up to 4 GB in a day, it does not go beyond that, may be due to some restrictions.

I check the error log file and found a single error type logged repetitively

Here is the error-log part

> WordPress database error Table 'asadm_main.wp_postmeta' doesn't exist for query
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(meta_id)
> FROM wp_postmeta
> WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent'
> AND meta_value='64'
> ```
>
> made by require('wp-blog-header.php'),
> require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
> include('/themes/magazine/magazine.php'), get_header, locate_template,
> load_template, require_once('/themes/magazine/header.php'),
> wp_nav_menu, walk_nav_menu_tree, call_user_func_array, Walker->walk,
> Walker->display_element, call_user_func_array,
> Walker_Nav_Menu->start_el, apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class'),
> call_user_func_array, astro_add_dropdown_class

I think this is theme specific issue. Can someone please explain what is going on and suggest me possible solutions for the same.

Comment: The message is pretty clear, the DB table you are trying to operate doesn't exist. How does you site even work with the `wp_postmeta` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot we don't know based on your post.

My guess is that you are using a plugin/theme that has hard coded "wp_" as the table prefix instead of getting it from the $wpdb variable...and that your table prefixes are NOT "wp_".

If you NEED to use the offending plugin/theme...you might be able to get away by creating a view.

```
CREATE VIEW wp_postmeta AS SELECT * FROM <put your actual postmeta table name here>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error (`'wp_postmeta' doesn't exist`) is evidence of a serious misconfiguration of WordPress.  That particular table is required for many parts of WordPress to function correctly.

These errors are certainly not related to your choice of theme unless there's something seriously defective about the theme you're using.

I suppose your error log size tops out at 4GB per day because of some file-size limitation somewhere in your system.

How can you fix this?

First, back up your site and your MySQL database.

Can you look at your MySQL database and see if the postmeta table has accidentally been renamed?  If so, change its name back.

Do you know when this started happening? Do you have a backup from shortly before it started happening? If so, restore wp_postmeta from that backup.

Like @AdamErstelle mentioned, you may have a defective plugin. To me it seems unwise to use a defective plugin on a mission critical WordPress installation.